# why Intellij Idea does not execute recording macro?

Tags: intellij-idea

I recorded macro using Intellij Idea 2019.01 version (Start recording, then using command + , to show the setting window, then stop recording and save the script), but when I executing macro command, the Intellij Idea status bar only show "scripts execution finished" and noting command effect show!!! Is there any wrong with my procedure. The os is mac os majave. I can not figure out where is the problem.

Add:

I open the micro edit view but has no steps,how to recognize the step is recorded?

[image]

Comment: To help you better, can you go to _Edit > Macros > Edit Macros_. With the Macro selected on the left so macro's steps shows on the right, take a screenshot and edit your question and paste in the screenshot. Also add a description of what it is you are trying to get your macro to do. Keep in mind that not all activity will work as a macro. But if you add this information, we may be able to help you determine why your macro is not working. Without that info, it is impossible to say why the macro is not working.

Comment: The micro step is null,I don't understand how to make my operate make effect.@Javaru